# tokbox how to detect if browser supports or not

Tags: javascript, php, opentok, tokbox

In tokbox , Is it possible to detect browsers and throw a not supported page.

But in tokbox demo ideo page they are doing this but i searched on their document but can't find how to do this stuff. can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Can you link the page where they detect browsers?

Comment: https://tokbox.com/platform this is the link they used...
check in lower version of browsers or load in ipad or iphone browsers

Comment: I worked with it and it printed a modal on the screen when the browser doesn't support WebRTC. I had this feature free because Tokbox itself check it.

Comment: can you share what you have done?

Comment: Did you try [this example](https://tokbox.com/opentok/tutorials/hello-world/js/demo.html)?

Comment: yes i have tried and implemented the video chat but some browsers not support the tokbox thats what i need to identify and show one popup , the browser is not supported

Comment: Does tokbox show a popup to say that? I remember that.

Answer (score 2):

Opentok has better APIs now:

You can use [network-test](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-network-test-js).

```
otNetworkTest.testQuality(null, function updateCallback() {
    // process intermediate results
}).then(results) {
    // Display UI based on results
}).catch(error, results) {
    switch (error.name) {
        case ErrorNames.UNSUPPORTED_BROWSER:
        // Display UI message about unsupported browser
        break;
        case ErrorNames.CONNECT_TO_SESSION_NETWORK_ERROR:
        // Display UI message about network error
        break;

        default:
        console.error('Unknown error .');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for the below code

```
OT.checkScreenSharingCapability(function(response) {
  if (!response.supported || response.extensionRegistered === false) {
    // This browser does not support screen sharing
  } else if (response.extensionInstalled === false) {
    // prompt to install the response.extensionRequired extension
  } else {
    // Screen sharing is available
  }
});
```

Let me know if you need further help

Comment: Or rather `checkSystemRequirements` for webRTC?